# jQuery elements not rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking at the code at

[creating jquery template](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1563-jQuery-Comments-Plug-in-To-Access-HTML-Comments-For-DOM-Templating.htm#blogcommentform)

I added several more comments templates to the div at the end of the html page but only the first is actually turned into html.  The variable jComments in the comments function is initialized and built up as follows

```
var jComments = $( [] );

jComments = jComments.add(
       "<div rel='" + strParentID + "'>" +
       objChildNode.nodeValue +
       "</div>"
       );
```

I'm sure from alerts I added that the comments I added are being incorporated into jComments but they are not being turned into html in the function in the html page with the code

```
$( "#list" ).append( jComments.html() );
```

Only the first is rendered. I can't find a description of the .add widget used in the comments function.  What kind of object is being built up here?  And how do I display the whole thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use Mustache? It's the best solution for templates in JS. Please give it a try and your code will be much cleaner and elegant than this. Please read [here](http://github.com/AF83/jquery.mustache) for more info.

However for your solution please try this:

```
// After you have properly populated jComments

jComments.each( function() {
    $( "#list" ).append( $(this).html() );
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that works.  I'll look at mustache.  But what is jComments?  An array?  How would I reference it with subscripts?

Comment: jComments is an array, you can reference it with subscripts like jComments[0] etc.